# Flutter Run truncated due large size during CI/CD using github actions and fastlane

Tags: flutter, github

I am using GitHub action and Fastlane to push my app based on commits and PRs to app store, but i realised that when the action start to Run `flutter build ios --release --no-codesign --verbose` the task take more than 30 min and ends with a message: "*This step has been truncated due to its large size. Download the full logs from the  menu once the workflow run has completed.*"

[image]

**my yml file:**

```js
# cd.yml
name: CD



on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - closed
    branches:
      - 'main'
      
jobs:
 deploy_ios:
    name: Deploy beta build to TestFlight
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code from ref
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{github.ref}}
      - name: Run Flutter tasks
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          flutter-version: '3.3.3'
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter build ios --release --no-codesign
      - name: increment major
        if: "contains(github.event.pull_request.title, 'major')"
        uses: maierj/fastlane-action@v1.4.0
        with: 
          lane: update_major
          subdirectory: ios
      - name: increment minor
        if: "contains(github.event.pull_request.title, 'minor')"
        uses: maierj/fastlane-action@v1.4.0
        with: 
          lane: update_minor
          subdirectory: ios
      - name: increment patch
        if: "contains(github.event.pull_request.title, 'patch')"
        uses: maierj/fastlane-action@v1.4.0
        with: 
          lane: update_patch
          subdirectory: ios
      - name: Deploy iOS Beta to TestFlight via Fastlane
        uses: maierj/fastlane-action@v1.4.0
        with:
          lane: _release_candidate
          subdirectory: ios
      - uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
        with:
          commit_message: Auto Commit

      
        env:
          APP_STORE_CONNECT_TEAM_ID: '${{ secrets.APP_STORE_CONNECT_TEAM_ID }}'
          DEVELOPER_APP_ID: '${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_APP_ID }}'
          DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER: '${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER }}'
          DEVELOPER_PORTAL_TEAM_ID: '${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_PORTAL_TEAM_ID }}'
          FASTLANE_APPLE_ID: '${{ secrets.FASTLANE_APPLE_ID }}'
          FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD: '${{ secrets.FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD }}'
          MATCH_PASSWORD: '${{ secrets.MATCH_PASSWORD }}'
          GIT_AUTHORIZATION: '${{ secrets.GIT_AUTHORIZATION }}'
          PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER: '${{ secrets.PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER }}'
          TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: '${{ secrets.TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}'
          TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER: '${{ secrets.TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER }}'
```

Comment: When it's finished you can download the full log, that might help. I'm having the same issue although my problem is I need to see in realtime what's happening.